# How to add a name for each element of a list in Jackson

Tags: javascript, java, json, groovy, jackson

Is it possible to set a name for each element of a list in JSON using JACKSON?

For example, I have the following JSON:

```
{"result": [
    {
      "name": "ABC",
      "age": "20"
    },{
      "name": "DEF",
      "age": "12"
    }
]}
```

But I need this:

```
{"result": [
    person: {    // << this is the name
      "name": "ABC",
      "age": "20"
    },
    person: {
      "name": "DEF",
      "age": "12"
    }
]}
```

Thanks to everybody!

***UPDATE***

Hi people!

I made a mistake! The correct form is the following:

```
{"result": [
    {
       person: {    // << this is the name
         "name": "ABC",
         "age": "20"
       }
    },
    {
       person: {
         "name": "DEF",
         "age": "12"
       }
    }
]}
```

Comment: That is not possible with JSON. Either you have an array or an object. If you have an object, keys must be unique.

Comment: there are no names for list items in JSON.  you would have to turn this into an object then.  but there can only be one value per key - so `person` two times will not work

Answer (score 0):

In plain Javascript, you could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and return a new object with person property.

```js
var object = { result: [{ name: "ABC", age: "20" }, { name: "DEF", age: "12" }] };

object.result = object.result.map(function (a) {
    return { person: a };
});

console.log(object);
```

Comment: in case, that is what OP actually asked, the same in groovy: `object.result.collect{ [person: it] }`

Comment: maybe, i do not know groovy.